# Check if at least two values per group of one df match in another one

Tags: r, group-by, match, conditional-statements, lookup

Let's say I have a data frame that looks like this.

df1:

```
ID      Skill        Community
1       IT              X
1       Analytics       X
1       ERP             X
2       Analytics       X
2       ERP             X
2       CRM             X
2       Finance         X
```

And another dataframe looking like this:

df2:

```
ID        Skill
3         Public Speaking
3         IT
3         Management
3         ERP
4         HR
4         Finance
...
```

My goal is to basically say that **if** a specific person (identified with its ID) has at least 2 skills in common with someone of the **df1**, then he should also be assigned to community X.

In the example above, ID nº3 should then also be assigned to community **X** (because he has IT and ERP in his skills, just like **ID nº1**), but not ID nº4 since he only has on matching skill with an ID nº2 (with Finance).

My expected output should then look like this for **df2**:

```
ID      Skill                 Community
3       Public Speaking          X
3       IT                       X
3       Management               X
3       ERP                      X
4       HR                      NULL
4       Finance                 NULL
.....
```

For the moment, I'm only using the command %in% with **df2[df2&Skill %in% df1$Skill,]** but this only check for **one specific skill**, and does not treat it by ID.

Do you have any idea on how should I approach this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RonakShah, just did it:)

Comment: What if person A shares two skills with person B, and also shares two skills with person C, but persons B and C share less than two skills? What is person A's community?

Comment: Then person A should be assigned to the community of person B and C. But person B will not be assigned to the community of person C

Comment: Ok, so there's no limit on the number of communities each person is assigned.

Comment: Indeed, there is no limit on the number of communities each person is assigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test this on your real-world dataset to see if the following works.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df3 <- df2 %>%
  left_join(df1, by = "Skill") %>%
  drop_na(ID.y) %>%
  count(ID.x, ID.y) %>%
  filter(n > 1) %>%
  distinct(ID.x) %>%
  mutate(Community = "X") %>%
  select(ID = ID.x, Community) %>%
  left_join(df2, ., by = "ID")
df3
#   ID           Skill Community
# 1  3 Public Speaking         X
# 2  3              IT         X
# 3  3      Management         X
# 4  3             ERP         X
# 5  4              HR      <NA>
# 6  4         Finance      <NA>
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "ID      Skill        Community
1       IT              X
                  1       Analytics       X
                  1       ERP             X
                  2       Analytics       X
                  2       ERP             X
                  2       CRM             X
                  2       Finance         X",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "ID        Skill
3         'Public Speaking'
3         IT
3         Management
3         ERP
4         HR
4         Finance",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: it looks like it is working! I have manually checked two examples. I'll check more and let you know. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)

df2[, Community := 
        'X'[any(tapply(df1$Skill, df1$ID, function(x) sum(Skill %in% x)) >= 2)]
    , by = ID]

df2

#    ID           Skill Community
# 1:  3 Public_Speaking         X
# 2:  3              IT         X
# 3:  3      Management         X
# 4:  3             ERP         X
# 5:  4              HR      <NA>
# 6:  4         Finance      <NA>
```